# hidden field is null on !IsPostBack and not null on IsPostBack

Tags: asp.net, request, page-lifecycle, hidden-field

First I'll apologize for the unclear title of my question. I wasn't sure how to succinctly describe my problem in a title.

I have a hidden field in my .aspx

```
<input type="hidden" name="hid1" value="0" />
```

I want to set the value of this field during the page load event, and if it is not a postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {

        // This doesn't work!
        Request.Form["hid1"] = "1";

    }

    if (Page.IsPostBack) {

        // This DOES work!
        Request.Form["hid1"] = "1";

    }
}
```

The problem is that the Request doesn't contain the hidden field in the Form array during the page load event when it's not a postback (ie - the first time the page is hit). Subsequent hits to the page (ie - postbacks) result in the Form array containing the hidden field.

I'm sure that it has to do with the lifecycle of the page, but what I really need to know is **how do I set the hidden field during the page load event and when it is not a postback?**

**EDIT:**
I really, really don't want to incorporate the runat="server" attribute!

Comment: Bob Kaufman has it right; it should be noted that when the page is not posted back, there is no form data sent with the request, so `Request.Form` isn't populated with key `"hid1"`.

Comment: Right, that's what I'd assumed as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a property in your page class and then modify the property value in your code:

```
    protected string HiddenFieldValue { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
            HiddenFieldValue = "postback";
        else
            HiddenFieldValue = "not postback";
    }
```

Then define the hidden form field like this so that it's value is set to the property value:

```
    <input type='hidden' id='hidden1' value='<%=HiddenFieldValue %>' />
```

If you only want to set the value form the property during a postback or non-postback you could add the condition as well:

```
    <input type='hidden' id='hidden1' value='<% if(IsPostBack) { %> <%=HiddenFieldValue%> <% } %>' />
```

Comment: Bam! That did it. Thanks for thinking outside of the box, Venr.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the input into a [`HiddenField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) control (or, at least, a [`runat="server"` input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputhidden.aspx)), and reference it by it's ID, rather than through `Request.Form`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hid1" value="0" />
```

try this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hid1" />
```

Then in your `Page_Load()`

```
hid1.Value = "whatever...";
```

It will be visible both before and after postback when you declare it in this manner.

Comment: Negative, Houston. See my reponse to tomlog's answer. This would work, but it's not the solution that I want. runat = mangled id's

Comment: i am not sure about JQuery, but if you use ClientId property, you should able to use that id in your JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it a server control by setting 'runat="server"' on the input control? Then it will be accessible from your code behind, and you will be able to set the value during the first page load.

Comment: In a nutshell, because I need to use the hidden field within some JQuery functions, and I wanted to keep the id from getting mangled due to runat="server". If I can't figure it out any other way, I'll go this route, but I'd be **very** surprised to find out there's not a way to access the hidden field from the page load on the initial page hit.

Comment: @Jagd -- this is one of my great fears of JQuery + ASP.NET. Use an idiom that looks at what your id ends with, like this: startDatePicker = $("input[id$='TextVisitStartDate']").datepicker(); TextVisitStartDate is an asp.net TextBox control.

Comment: @Bob - Yeah, that's typically what I do (id$='_whatever'), but I was trying to get away from that this one time. Sure seems like a lot of work though, and I'm beginning to think it's not worth the pain.

Comment: Surely you can set a JavaScript/JQuery variable with the ClientId of the control during the page load. That way you always have the exact control id to use in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you access that field through a style class and use runat server=?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by accessing it through a style class. Can you clarify or give me an example of how to do so?

Comment: @Jagd - you can add an arbitrary class to your hidden input element which you can use as a pseduo-id that asp.net won't mess with. For example: `<input type="hidden" name="hid1" value="0" class="hid1" />`. Then you can access it in jQuery using the class selector syntax without sweating Asp.Net's generated ids: `$(".hid1").function()`