# hidden variable does not have value after postback asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnField" name="hdnField"/>

Request.Form.Set("hdnField", x.ToString());
```

after the page post back the value is not there.

I am new to this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472988/2118383)**

You could define a property in your page class and then modify the property value in your code:

```
    protected string HiddenFieldValue { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
            HiddenFieldValue = x.ToString();
        else
            HiddenFieldValue = x.ToString();
    }
```

Then define the hidden form field like this so that it's value is set to the property value:

```
    <input type='hidden' id='hdnField' value='<%=HiddenFieldValue %>' />
```

If you only want to set the value form the property during a postback or non-postback you could add the condition as well:

```
    <input type='hidden' id='hdnField' value='<% if(IsPostBack) { %> <%=HiddenFieldValue%> <% } %>' />
```

Comment: this worked but the hdnField is part of user control which is part of a aspx page, so back and forth the value is disappearing, any suggestion for retaining that value in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You should use `asp:HiddenField` tag provided by asp rather than using the basic HTML input.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" Value="" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Using this, you can read and write value in c# using `hdnField.Value` and in jQuery using `$('#hdnField').val()`.